# How to search for Metro-UI Windows 8 apps' repositories in Sourceforge?

Tags: search, sourceforge, open-source

When I searched in GitHub/Bitbucket everything was okay because of the repositories' names (and probably because of different search engines), but on this site it just lists the apps' names and it gives tons of unneeded results

P.S: currently I'm trying something like "windows 8"